# Jquery XSS issue while appending the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I am facing a problem now like When I append some data to the HTML using jquery , The contents got erased and XSS was appended to the body,

Actually got the output when I appended like this

```
function init() {
    var data = TABLE_DATA;
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        var tablerow = jQuery('<tr></tr>');

        var tableTD = jQuery('<td></td>');
        tableTD.text(data[i].id);
        var tableTD1 = jQuery('<td></td>');
        tableTD1.text(data[i].name);
        var tableTD2 = jQuery('<td></td>');
        tableTD2.text(data[i].thumbnailUrl);
        var tableTD3 = jQuery('<td></td>');
        tableTD3.text(data[i].price);   
        tablerow.append(tableTD,tableTD1,tableTD2,tableTD3);
        $('.content').append(tablerow)
    }
}
```

Data will be a json and the output is successfully appended to the table

But When I do like this, I got XSS appended to the body erasing all the appended Jquery tags,

```
function init() {
    var data = TABLE_DATA;
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        var tablerow = jQuery('<tr></tr>')
        tablerow.append('<td>' + data[i].id+'</td>')
        tablerow.append('<td>' + data[i].name+'</td>')
        tablerow.append('<td>' + data[i].thumbnailUrl+'</td>')
        tablerow.append('<td>' + data[i].price+'</td>')
        $('.contents').append(tablerow)
    }
}
```

Actually Why is this happening here, what is the fix for this. What change in code must be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `append()` will add the data to the page, and try to parse it into elements, which can include executing javascript.  `text()` on the other hand, adds the value to an element as a textNode, of which if the value contains scripting, will not execute.

Comment: @Taplar : So earlier when I was doing this, the issue didnt happend, but for now, it is happening, So in future should I follow the first method always ?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  If there is the chance that the data you are appending could have xss in it, `text()` is one way of keeping it from executing.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the suggestion, is there any other ways that this can be prevented

Comment: Depending on your language, there are libraries out there for cleansing data put on the page, though most of those that I have ran into are related to server side building of the pages.  I think text() is a valid approach, personally.